# A family of countable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I}$ be a family of countable sets such that for any $\alpha, \beta \in I$, either $A_\alpha \subset A_\beta$ or $A_\beta \subset A_\alpha$. Is it true that $\bigcup A_\alpha$ countable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. The least uncountable ordinal, $\omega_1$ is the union of all the smaller ordinals, all of which are countable, and all of which make a linearly ordered family as in your question.

However, you can prove that under the requirements you pose, the only counterexamples are those of cardinality $\aleph_1$. So without additional hypothesis (specifically the continuum hypothesis) you cannot use the real numbers as a counterexample.

Also, your attempt to use the rational numbers is futile, since the set of rational numbers is countable.

Comment: Ehm... yeah... What he said. (; (I really should get my hands on a model $M$ - can't compete with that type speed.)

Comment: Sorry, I typed this one on a Nexus 6p...

Comment: That's just mean...

Comment: I'm a lean, mean, mathing machine!

Comment: Always a pleasure to hang out with you.

Comment: Just wait until you hang out with me in real life...

Comment: Long overdue... I was really looking forward to grab some falafels with you in Israel. Too bad I couldn't make it that time.

Comment: Don't worry. Better beers in Germany than falafel in Israel.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, $I$ doesn't have to be countable. But in general, your result does hold only if $I$ is countable. Take for example $I = \omega_{1}$ and for each $\alpha \in I$ let $A_{\alpha} = \alpha$. Then for $\alpha \le \beta < \omega_{1}$ we have $A_{\alpha} \subseteq A_{\beta}$, each $A_{\alpha}$ is countable, but $\omega_{1} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_{\alpha}$ is uncountable.